# Matrix concatenation or merging

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, concatenation

[image: new output from edited data]In my project, i have a matrix of order 11X24 but I need to convert/merge/concatenate it to a matrix of order 35X11 means 35 rows and 24 columns.

What I need is to add 24 rows of rows and then the 11 rows of the other matrix just like horizontal concatenation in Matlab.

The way the first matrix is computed is given by the following code and it is complex matrix so defined by double complex

```
//take real and imaginary part to build e_m matrix
re = fopen("realpart.txt","r");
for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
    for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
        fscanf(re,"%lf",&real[i][j]);
    }
}

fclose(re);
im = fopen("imagepart.txt","r");
for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
    for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
        fscanf(im,"%lf",&imag[i][j]);
    }
}

fclose(im);

//compute e_m matrix
for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
    for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
        e_m[i+ROWS*j].r = real[i][j];
        e_m[i+ROWS*j].i = imag[i][j]; //defined cols-by-cols (i.e. z[0][1] is z[35])
    }
}
```

Where the files are being read by two .txt files and the output is e_m.txt file attached to this post.  To concatenate it i am using the following code:

```
for(d=0;d<ord1;d++){
    for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
        if(d>23){
            e_mm[d+ord1*j].r = real[i][j];
            e_mm[d+ord1*j].i = imag[i][j]; //defined cols-by-cols (i.e. z[0][1] is z[35]
        }
        else
            e_mm[d+ord1*j].r= 0;
        e_mm[d+ord1*j].i= 0;
    }
}

FILE* file7=fopen("/dev/conc.txt","w");
for(i=0;i<ord1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
        fprintf(file7,"%lf\t %lf\t", e_mm[i+ord1*j].r,e_mm[i+ord1*j].i);
    }
    fprintf(file7,"\n");
}
fclose(file7);
for(i=0;i<ord1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<COLS;j++)
    if (i>23) {
        concat[i].r=e_m[i].r;
        concat[j].i=e_m[j].i;
    }
    else
        concat[i].r = 0;
    concat[j].i = 0;
}
FILE* file8=fopen("/dev/concat.txt","w");

for(i=0;i<ord1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
        fprintf(file8,"%lf\t %lf\t", concat[i].r, concat[j].i);
    }
    fprintf(file8,"\n");
}

fclose(file8);
*/
```

But the output is not what i need. Can someone guide me what i am doing wrong ?
[image: e_m image 11x24 matrix]

declaration of some veriable is here.. since the code is a lengty thats why i had included the whole code.

```
doublereal  real[ROWS][COLS];                //real coefficient to build E_m matrix
  doublereal  imag[ROWS][COLS];                //imaginary coefficient to build E_m matrix
  doublereal  real1[ROWS][COLS];                //real coefficient to build E_m matrix by me
  doublereal  imag1[ROWS][COLS];  
  doublecomplex e_m[ROWS*COLS]; 
  ROWS = 11;
  integer COLS = 24;        
  integer ldvt=COLS;    
  integer ord1 = 35;doublecomplex e_m[ROWS*COLS];              
  doublecomplex e_mm[ord1*COLS];
  doublecomplex e_m1[ord1*COLS];
```

Edited line of code

```
 //take real and imaginary part to build e_m1 matrix
            re1 = fopen("realpart.txt","r");
             for(d=23;d<ord1;d++){
             for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
              fscanf(re1,"%lf",&real1[d][j]);
               }
              }
              fclose(re1);

            im1 = fopen("imagepart.txt","r");
              for(d=23;d<ord1;d++){
              for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
                fscanf(im1,"%lf",&imag1[d][j]);
              }
             }
            fclose(im1);

                            for(d=0;d<ord1;d++){
                            for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
                                if(d<24)  {
                                      e_m1[d*COLS+j].r =  0;
                                      e_m1[d*COLS+j].i =  0;  //defined cols-by-cols (i.e. z[0][1] is z[35])
                                                }
                                                    else   {

                                                            e_m1[d*COLS+j].r =  real1[d][j];
                                                            e_m1[d*COLS+j].i =  imag1[d][j];
                                                           }
                                                }
                           }


            FILE* file5=fopen("/dev/e_m1.txt","w");
                    for(d=0;d<ord1;d++){
                       for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
                        fprintf(file5,"%.3f\t %.3f\t",e_m1[d*COLS+j].r,e_m1[d*COLS+j].i);[![enter image description here][4]][4]
                     }
                        fprintf(file5,"\n");
                    }
                   fclose(file5);
```

Comment: Please format your code!

Comment: Add example Input and output and the output of your implementation.

Comment: What is the concrete problem?

Comment: While formatting your code, I note there are two `else` statements in the second section of code, that do not have curly braces, meaning only the first statement would be executed as part of the else.  Would that change your output?

Comment: as you can see in the outputs image uploaded the required matrix is not what i need i tried two different arrangments but in both the result is not what i need. yah but else statement is related to the part where the rows have to be zero but the problem which i am facing is in the part where the data from original matrix have to be exactly same. As you can see in one method i am getting one column correct but then other is zero and then correct

Comment: You should really start this by trying to do whatever you want to do to a 2x3 to a 5x2 or something.

Comment: Did you fix it meanwhile? Why is `e_m` and `e_mm` 1-dimensional?

Comment: they are not  1-dimensional as you can see in the images uploaded they're multidimensional. I am having a problem in the looping mechanism where the first rows have to be zero and then the data from the files which I am reading has to be written on remaining rows. @yacc

Comment: There are declarations/definitions missing for `ROW`, `COL`, `ord1`, `real`, `imag`, `e_m` and `e_mm`. Update your code to show the relevant lines.

Comment: i had added the declarations of the missing in the code above. as the main code is very lengthy due to which i had not added the whole code

Comment: This is what I addressed in my recent comment. You are declaring `e_m` and `e_mm` as 1-d arrays. Why did you do that? In your code you now face the endeavor to map a 2-d matrix to a 1-d array. And this is a potential source for wrong assignments. Why didn't you declare e_m and e_mm 2-dimensional?

Comment: And what is `e_m1`? It's not used in the code. For the sake of clarity, bear in mind that code has to be indented properly, and identifiers (such as for variables or files) should be speaking for themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and sorry for the confusion. as you can see the output of e_m in the uploaded image its correct and i want to get the same output as i had obtained from e_m but with the addition of rows of zeros in beginning. if for the same declaration is correct and I am getting what i needed(for the case of e_m) then I think i can get the same for the case of e_mm with just addition of rows in beginning. that's why I declared them in the same way and sorry about e_m1 I was using it to try two different approaches for the same thing.

Comment: The way you're mapping to the 1-d array looks weird. I'd use `i*COLS+j` instead of `i+ROWS*j`. Where you use loop counter `d` you access `real[i][j]`, but `i` is always the same. And the remark from @roelofs about the missing braces for the two *else* blocks is right. The least you should do is some refactoring to make the code more readable.

Comment: I made some changes in my code with the help of some of the suggestions which you people gave and few changes which i made as well. now i am getting what i needed but the only problem is that the first row of the data is not being written but all other rows are correct. i am getting first 24 rows as zeros and the remaining 11 rows with data, which i need and also the number of columns is correct which is 24, can anyone suggest me why I am not getting the first row of data. the code changes which I made and the output are uploaded in the main code section.

Comment: if you compare the two images uploaded you will see that the first row of the e_m is not present in e_m1 image.